# How to get some return back in jQuery Fn feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery.fn feature and I need to return some values back into script.Please help

According to below sample I need to return 't' value and Im expecting to assign it to 'T'

```
$.fn.Hello = function() {     
  return this.each(function() {
    var t = "something";
    // my code
  };
}

// Binding
var T = $('ele').Hello(args);    
console.log(T);
```

Comment: You can't return anything from the `each()` handler function. All you are returning is the result of `each()` itself, which is the same as `this`, ie. the jQuery object which `Hello()` was called on in the first place.

Comment: You aren't supposed to do something like what you want... not really, anyway... what you are doing now is correct - returning the matched elements back so you can chain them.  The problem with what you *want* to do is that your return value would likely lose its meaning because you have no good way of matching the element in the collection to the part of the return value.  You should probably rethink what you are doing. What, exactly, are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Given that you are looping, it's not clear what you expect the returned value to be.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear, what type of variable is 't' and how is it modified, but you could declare and return it outside of `each()`:

```
$.fn.Hello = function() {
  var t;
  this.each(function() {
    t = "something";
    // your code
  };
  return t;
}

// Binding
var T = $('ele').Hello(args);    
console.log(T);
```

Comment: This will not return the t as I expected any way thanks Mikhali

Comment: @Dhanan So what type of returned value are you expecting then?

Comment: Hi @LeroyStav,

I need to get some values back depend on the situation. T supposed to be an object any way.

Comment: @Dhanan as everyone is telling you, you should explain what you want to return.  "Some object" implies that you are returning *one* value, yet your response of "This will not return the t as I expected any way thanks Mikhali" implies otherwise.  If you want to return an array, then `var t = [];` and `t.push('something');` in the `each`.  If you want a count then `var t = 0;` and `t++;` in the `each` (both of these examples modify the answer above)  The solution here depends *entirely* on what it is you want to achieve yet you are seemingly refusing to tell us what that is!

Comment: Hi All, I'm writing this as for a solution to complex functionality so thats why i didnt paste all code here. I think its not much valuable to knowing is it an object or array. any way still i need to return some value which is inside the $.fn and i need to return that value back again. Much appreciated